# Is boost::any movable?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-any

This code compiles but I don't think it does what I intended, that is, move, don't copy, the `boost::any` object that was created on the stack into a `std::vector<boost::any>`

```
boost::any var;
var = std::string("StackOverflow");

std::vector<boost::any> vm;
vm.push_back(std::move(var));

for (auto& i : vm)
{
  std::cout << boost::any_cast<std::string>(i) << std::endl; // yes a copy exists 
}
std::cout << boost::any_cast<std::string>(var) << std::endl; // but this copy still exists too. was it not moved??
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you look into `boost/any.hpp` and observe its source code (at least find for *move* word) you can found that it is totally C++11 unaware (unfortunately)!
so you'd better to use `boost::any::swap` to *simulate* move assign (if you still want to use `boost::any` at all)

Comment: I checked the source 1.53 and didn't see any evidence but boost codes tends to be beyond me so thought I am missing something. But then I saw this discussion https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6999

Comment: @user841550 there is nothing to miss ;) -- it is ~254 lines long and ~6k in size :). you ought to trust your eyes more :) (and believe in self)